# How to create and write csv in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I want to create and write csv file in ruby on rails. I'm using ruby 1.9.2 version. Most of the sites are recommended Fastercsv. But apart from that how csv is used to create and write csv files in ruby

Answer (score 1):

FasterCSV is no longer needed in 1.9.2 - use ruby's built-in CSV class. The documentation has plenty of examples to get you started:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 1):

hope this will be helpful

http://satishonrails.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-generate-csv-files-in-rails/

https://github.com/dasil003/csv_builder

http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoExportDataAsCSV

Comment: As Thilo has highlighted below, the CSV coolness is now baked into ruby. Although the syntax from FasterCSV is largely preserved in the CSV module these references are unlikely to be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem [julia_builder](https://github.com/stevenbarragan/julia_builder#installation), you can export your data pretty easily.